# How to insert up arrow in microsoft word for mac using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office

Is there a way to insert uparrow that is not a wingding in word with a keyboard shortcut? Whenever I insert the symbol from the character browser it switches my font to wingdings and it's frustrating because then I have to manually switch back to the original font.

Comment: What is your original font?  Does it contain an uparrow? If not, there is no way to avoid changing the font.

Comment: Times New Roman or Arial?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [Dash (Free with IAP)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12&uo=4&at=11ld6n&ct=dash) or [TextExpander (Paid)](https://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) to define custom shortcuts for those symbols. Next time you want to insert `Up Arrow`, you just have to type `.upar` and it won’t change your fonts (since they’re pasted as plain text).

**Update:** I didn’t realize that you change the font manually. This still can be solved with TextExpander (but not Dash). All you need to is to choose Rich Text (selecting font that have `Up Arrow`) for the expanded custom arrow, and put a space afterward in the font you use in Microsoft Words.

Eg. You use **Monotype Corsiva** in Microsoft Words — by assuming that it doesn’t contain `Up Arrow`. Define your expanded words where `Up Arrow` is selected as **Lucida Grande** that supports arrows. Right after the arrow, change the space into **Monotype Corsiva**. This way, you use two fonts in Microsoft Words, but only `Up Arrow` is in Lucida Grande.

[image: Custom Up Arrow Shortcuts for Mac]

P.S. There is an Alfred’s worflow called [Symbols](http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1404-find-and-paste-unicode-symbols-arrow-triangles-greek-and-more/) that lets you search through the unicode, paste it into your active Text Editor. Take a look at how it works.

Comment: The font will of course have to change if the one being used does not have an uparrow in it, plain text does not change that fact.

Comment: I didn’t notice this one. It sounds to me that he can use **Up Arrow** if other font is selected. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: If he doesn't want to change his fonts, he has to use an "original" font that has uparrow in it.

Comment: I don't have the powerpack for alfred :/ you need it to add workflows right?

Comment: @user45467 yes, you need Powerpack to use Alfred, but you probably don’t need it for your problem. Check out my updated that users TextExpander for text replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that must be a Word "feature" to change to Wingdings, instead of an OS function.

If this is something you need frequently, you can try [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/143564/55567) from @0942v865:

To summarize: copy your favorite arrow symbol and put it into a text file.

```
{
    "~a" = ("insertText:", "⬆");
}
```

Save it to: `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`

(You will probably have to create the folder.)

Restart your application, and now you should be able to type <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (a for arrow) to get an up-arrow...