# Replace keyboard shortcut for ⌥ + d

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I want to replace the keyboard shortcut for
<kbd>⌥Option</kbd>  + <kbd>d</kbd> = **∂**
with
<kbd>⌥Option</kbd>  + <kbd>d</kbd> = **ð**

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try any of [these options](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/keyboard-remapping-in-os-x-10-9)?

Comment: KeyboardMaestro solved my problem, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a third-part software. Thanks!

Comment: yes, a solution w/o 3rd party requirement is ideal!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a plain text file with this in it (in TextEdit, use `Format > Make Plain Text`):

```
{
    "~d" = ("insertText:", "ð");
}
```

Call it `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` (make sure to uncheck “When no extension is provided, use .txt”), and save it in `~/Library/KeyBindings/`. (You can press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and paste that path.)

The `"~d"` means Option-D, and the `("insertText:", "ð")` means it will insert a ð character instead of ∂.

You will have to restart your applications in order for this setting to take effect.

Comment: I have no KeyBindings in my Library folder.. I use OSX 10.9.4

Comment: @hiru: Then make that folder yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to [create a custom keyboard layout](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45402/4408). I can easily type symbols like `→`, `←`, , and `♥` with [my custom layout](http://git.io/qwerty).